# How to get the servecallid of the call in azure communication call in android

Tags: android, azure, azure-communication-services

I have downloaded and configured azure communication calling ui package locally from github. I'm able to start the azure call using callcomposite. I'm trying to get the azure call server id using the code I got from the documentation but I'm not able to get the servercallid.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/voice-video-calling/get-server-call-id

```
try {
    String serverCallId = call.getInfo().getServerCallId().get();
    // Send serverCallId to your recording server to start the call recording.
} catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {

} catch (UnsupportedOperationException unsupportedOperationException) {

}
```

Comment: As  I understand you’re referring to the Azure doc sample, servercall Id is generated or available only after call is connected , hence ACS returns only once state `connected`
Take a look at this sample which can retrieve the serverCallId – In this case, we are waiting for the call to be connected and then the request for the serverCallId is made. Hence, the call needs to be connected first before you can query for the serverCallid 
Ref sample: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/communication-services-javascript-quickstarts/blob/main/ui-library-add-call-recording/app/src/App.tsx

Comment: @AjayKumar how to retrieve serverCallId in android sdk